# Getting domain user while also allowing anonymous users in C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, identity

Currently having issues grabbing the domain user and also allowing anonymous users to access the page.  As I have it set up in web.config currently, it makes anonymous users log in.  I would just like to allow anyone but grab the domain user if it exists.

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <!--<allow users="*" />-->
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

Above is currently the only setup I can use to grab the domain user, however it asks anonymous users to log in still.

Trying two methods to grab the domain user:

```
string CurrentUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
string CurrentUser2 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

Am I going about this all wrong?

Edit: Following what @MethodMan said, I'm using the UserPrincipal.

```
UserPrincipal CurrentUser = UserPrincipal.Current; 
ViewBag.CurrentUser = CurrentUser.DisplayName.ToString();
```

However, I'm getting the following error on IIS but not IIS Express:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.
```

Not sure what it means because I'm only using UserPrincipal.

Comment: if you are wanting allow anyone then remove the authorization and use PrincipalContext to determine if the user based on their login user name is in the domain or not.. this is actually quite simple but it you are wanting those outside the DMZ anonymous access.. I would suggest working with your system Admin in regards to setting that up.. or go the `Active Directory` Route...

Comment: I'll try going down the PrincipalContext route. It should allow anyone and also grab the user if it exists?

Comment: I got this going on IIS Express but had the following error when on the IIS server.  ``Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.`` I'm using ``UserPrincipal CurrentUser = UserPrincipal.Current; ViewBag.CurrentUser = CurrentUser.DisplayName.ToString();`` Unfortunately searching on google directs me back to using my previous ``HttpContext`` methods instead... Any thoughts?

Comment: if you are going to update code.. please edit your original question and post the updated code there not in your comments.. also the error is telling you exactly what the problem is

Comment: I edited it into my OP. I'm sorry for my naivety, but I really don't understand the error message because I'm not using a GroupPrincipal. Is it getting a GroupPrincipal as the return value for UserPrincipal.Current instead of a UserPrincipal?